# Save a CBitmap to .bmp file

Tags: bitmap, mfc, cdc, cbitmap

I'm working with a `CBitmap` object using a `CDC`. When I'm finished with it I want to save it to a file. I have seen something about a process with that code [LINK](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/708dc691-3e73-48d7-b786-631db656dcc9/saving-cbitmap-as-a-bmp-file-in-mfc?forum=vcmfcatl):

```
CFile file;
if(file.Open(szFileName, CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite))
{ 
    file.Write(&bh, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
    file.Write(&(bi.bmiHeader), sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
    file.Write(lpBitmapBits, 3 * nWidth * nHeight);
    file.Close();
}
```

My doubt is about `BITMAPFILEHEADER` and `BITMAPINFOHEADER`. How can I fill them with a given `CBitmap` or `CDC`?

Comment: I don't think this will work ... you could use the CImage class ... it has a Save method ...

Comment: Yes. Finally I did it...
Easier than I expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try this:

```
CImage image;

image.Attach(CDCvar.GetCurrentBitmap());
image.Save(_T(".\\test.bmp"), Gdiplus::ImageFormatBMP);
```